# How to scrape the autocomplete value

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am unable to scrape the autocomplete values .

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urlparse

url="https://www.facebook.com/users/login"
htmltext=urllib.urlopen(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(htmltext)
for tag in soup.findAll('form',autocomplete=True):
    raw=tag['autocomplete']
    print raw
```

Comment: Autocomplete is performed client side, typically using data from some ajax call to an api. You need a browser to run the client side code needed for that, or you have to access the api directly.